# Google Directory API Quickstart - How to retrieve aliases

Tags: javascript, api, alias, google-developers-console

I am trying to retrieve a list of all users in a Google Admin console with their email aliases listed. I was able to retrieve all users using the sample in the documentation, but am having trouble finding the parameters needed to request the aliases in Javascript. Here is what I have now.

```
 async function listUsers() {
    let response;
    try {
      const request = {
        'customer': 'my_customer',
        'orderBy': 'email',
        \\ this is wrong
        'aliases': [
            {
                object (UserAlias)
            }
        ]
        \\
      };
      response = await gapi.client.directory.users.list(request);
    } catch (err) {
      document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
      return;
    }
```

I tried using the aliases object listed here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users.aliases/list

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! To retrieve a list of users along with their email aliases, you should use the projection parameter with the value full in your request. The aliases field is not needed for the request you're making. Here's the updated code:

```
async function listUsers() {
  let response;
  try {
    const request = {
      'customer': 'my_customer',
      'orderBy': 'email',
      'projection': 'full', // Add this line
    };
    response = await gapi.client.directory.users.list(request);
  } catch (err) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
    return;
  }

  // Process the response and display the user email addresses and aliases
  const users = response.result.users;
  for (const user of users) {
    console.log('User email: ' + user.primaryEmail);
    if (user.aliases) {
      console.log('Aliases: ' + user.aliases.join(', '));
    } else {
      console.log('No aliases');
    }
  }
}
```

This code sets the projection parameter to full, which includes all the user information including aliases. After making the request, the response is processed to display the user's primary email address and any aliases they have.

For more information on the projection parameter, refer to the Google Admin SDK Directory API documentation: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list